# failed to add as session directory: path . is not an absolute path in Singularity

Tags: singularity-container

Following [Singularity-tutorial](https://singularity-tutorial.github.io/02-basic-usage/), I do in singularity version 3.5.2 (in a linux machine):

```
singularity shell lolcow_latest.sif
```

and I see in stderr:

```
INFO:    Convert SIF file to sandbox...
INFO:    Cleaning up image...
FATAL:   container creation failed: failed to add  as session directory: path . is not an absolute path
```

How do I enter the container?

Thank you!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. What is the output when run with `singularity --debug ...`? Have you tried with a recent (3.7+) version of singularity?

Comment: @tsnowlan. Thank you. Aside from the error that I report in the question, using `--debug` in the `prepareAutofs()` step I see `no mount point`. Is it related to the problem?

Comment: Try rebuilding/pulling the image (it's possible there was a problem and something got corrupted). If it's still not working, please update the questions with the exact command you used to create the image and the full `--debug` output from `singularity shell`